# C# method to check if character is markup or not

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Is there any method in the .NET framework which will return true if a given character is an XML markup character? That is, one of the characters, `'"<>_&`, and any others that may exist.

I understand I can go for a simple string search also, but was wondering if a built-in method exists which would not rely on manually typing the characters.

Comment: I don't think so...  but would love to be proven wrong!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use this code

```
const string XMLCHARS = "'\"\\<>&";


if(XMLCHARS.Contains(c))
{
 --
}
```

Comment: That's actually what I am using now :)

Answer (score 4):

You may checkout the [following KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316063).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I actually don't want to do any replacement. Simply a function of the format, bool IsXMLEscape(char ch).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure the term "XML markup character" (or rather a context-independent function for detecting these) makes much sense, since some of the characters you list only have special meaning depending on the context in which they appear (such as `'` and `"`, which are normal characters if they appear outside of a tag).

Apart from that, you could always write your own such  function:

```
bool IsMarkupCharacter(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '\'':
        case '\"':
        case '<':
        case '>':
        case '&':
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Of course you would want to check this against the XML specification to check if it's truly complete. (I didn't include `_` from your list, by the way; it is not special to XML in any way, AFAIK.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are right, it's not actually part of XML markup character. So that means, there isn't any built in function for that?

Comment: @Gunner, I suppose not, because determining the meaning of these characters is context-dependent (as I said). That is, to get truly useful and correct results, you'd need a simple form of an XML parser that processes a character stream, not just a function taking a single character. But if the method shown in my or Stecya's answer suffices, just use that.

Comment: Yes, the term "XML markup character" simply isn't well-defined. For example, within an attribute value, double-quotes is a special character if you're using double-quotes to delimit the attribute, but apostrophe is special if you delimit the attribute with apostrophe. In text nodes, neither quotes nor apostrophe is special.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension

```
public static class CharExtension
{
    public static bool IsXmlMarkup(this char charecter)
    {
        if(charecter == '\'' || charecter == '\"' || e.t.c) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

and then just use

```
char c = '\'';
var res = c.IsXmlMarkup();
```